# GIS 3D Visualisation options

Tags: 3d, maps, gis

Looking to specifically map new planting schemes for forestry and currently use QGIS (Qgis2threejs) for this, but finding it struggles with the larger scale planting schemes.

Does anyone know of software or other plugins that would be useful?

Trying to avoid ArcScene if possible.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid ArcScene?  That would help to identify something that you *do* want.

Comment: Not an ESRI shop and going with ArcScene would limit usage.